# Unexpected ioctl behavior on symlinks

Tags: linux, symlink, ioctl, udev

I'm currently working with a HID device. It has two setup modes : HID, and RS232. So I wrote a little script to switch him to RS232, whenever it's plugged as a HID device, using this udev rule :

```
ENV{ID_VENDOR}=="Vendor", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="001d", ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="usbhid",\
SYMLINK+="hid_device", RUN+="/path/to/HID_to_serial"
```

The script is as follows :

```
// HID_to_serial.c
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

//#define DEFAULT_DEVICE_PATH   "/dev/hidraw0"
#define DEFAULT_DEVICE_PATH     "/dev/hid_device"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  int fd = open(DEFAULT_DEVICE_PATH, O_RDWR);

  if (fd < 0)
  {
      perror("Unable to open device");
      return 1;
  }

  // Very specific report descriptor
  const char buf[64] = {  0x02, 0x0b, 0x02, 0x04, 0x42, 0x40, 0x10, 0x42,
                          0x62, 0x10, 0x42, 0x42, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                          0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 };

  int res = ioctl(fd, _IOC(_IOC_WRITE|_IOC_READ, 'H', 0x06, 64), buf);
  if (res < 0)
      perror("ioctl");
  else
      printf("Device was succesfully switched back to serial mode!\n");

  return 0;
}
```

Now, usually, when I plug the device, Linux gives it the `/dev/hidraw0` file. And when I use my script on `/dev/hidraw0`, it works perfectly. The report descriptor used in the script is correct, and everything works as intended : the HID device switches back to RS232 mode.

**However**, when I try to use my script on the `/dev/hid_device` symlink created by the udev rule, it doesn't work 99% of the time, telling me `ioctl: Invalid argument`. The even stranger thing is that it works, but 1% of the time (maybe even less often).

Does anyone have any idea where this might come from, and how to fix it, or work around it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

It lies in my udev rule : it's not precise enough.

When I plug the device, linux creates two `character special` device files in `/dev/` : `hidraw0`, and `input/event15` (in my case). They share a lot of environment values, like for example their `ID_VENDOR_ID`, or their `ID_USB_DRIVER`. However, they do not share the same `MAJOR`.

So what I did was add `ENV{MAJOR}=="correct_major"` in my udev rule, and now my symlink is linked to the correct device file.

It also explains why it worked sometimes : I guess that because of the lack of details in the udev rule, sometimes the symlink was linked to the correct device file, sometimes not.